# How to ignore generated cpp files (from swig/python) in Coverity Scan?

Tags: python, c++, git, swig, coverity

I've got a C++ project with Python bindings generated by SWIG. I get a generated file `python/libproj_wrap.cpp` from SWIG. This file is listed in `.gitignore`.

I'm running Coverity Scan through Travis. It seems like Coverity Scan tries to run `git blame` on this, which fails:

```
fatal: no such path 'python/libproj_wrap.cpp' in HEAD
[WARNING] An error occurred while executing command at '/home/travis/build/unhammer/proj/python':
COMMAND: '/usr/bin/git blame -p proj_wrap.cpp' failed. Error code 128. Proceeding...
```

and I get no scan results. Is there a way to tell Coverity Scan to ignore `.gitignore`'d stuff, or should I just run the scan on a build configured without SWIG bindings?

Answer (score 0):

That would happen if `python/libproj_wrap.cpp` was tracked *before* being added to the `.gitignore`.

Just to be sure, try and untrack it:

```
git rm --cached python/libproj_wrap.cpp
git commit -m "untrack python/libproj_wrap.cpp"
git push
```

And see if Travis is still trying a `git blame` on that file.

Comment: `fatal: pathspec 'python/libproj_wrap.cpp' did not match any files`, so that's not it

Comment: @unhammer that might be more on the  Coverity Scan Dashboard side (https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/coverity-scan/)